# imagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo usage

Tags: ios, swift

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let image = (info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage) {
        self.memeImage.image = image
    }
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

`info` is a dictionary with two values. But in:

```
info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
```

There is only one string value `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` in it.

Why? And how to use it?

Comment: see the answer let me know if you have any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
```

`info` is the dictionary and this is a **collection whose elements are key-value pairs.**

**Here the string type key:-** `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`

**The value is:-** `UIImage` object

Also, you can see here **all keys**: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/editing_information_keys

Comment: but key-value pair is  like that                                                                      `var airports: [String: String] = ["YYZ": "Toronto Pearson", "DUB": "Dublin"]`

Comment: @zetao info is a collection of a key-value pair that is prepared by the technology not by you if you want to see this you can print it.

Comment: `let UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage = "TechnologyValue"` This is a declaration something like this in the framework but technology gives us the variable that contains the original key.

Comment: Thanks.I will have a try.

Comment: @zetao if the answer corrects so plz accept the answer. happy to help :)

Comment: does that mean we just need to provide one key-value pair to the info?

Comment: @zetao why do you need to provide the key-value pair to the info? That delegate method provides some information you have to use according to your requirements.